# Why is autocorrelation matrix used instead of output matrix while performing SVD in ESPRIT Algorithm

Tags: autocorrelation, svd, doa

The ESPRIT algorithm described in wiki or any other literature suggest the usage of autocorrelation matrix instead of output matrix while performing SVD as one of the steps towards estimating DOA. It appears that the output matrix (Y) can be used, mathematically speaking (wiki also shows the steps), but there must be some benefits of using auto-correlation matrix instead.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_signal_parameters_via_rotational_invariance_techniques

I have not been able to identify this benefit. Could someone point me to any literature or describe the benefits?

Comment: what is the "output matrix" in this context?

Comment: It is the receiver signal represented in matrix form. (Term Y in the wiki link). If you have M receivers, it is of the size MxT where T is the number of time instances when the measurement is taken.

Comment: but that is just the observations. Can you explain why you'd you think that ESPRIT would work with that? After all, the whole point of the signal space model is that your matrix represents the correlations! (without you actually explaining why mathematically you think that should work, the answer to this question is "no, that's not going to work. Literature: read the original ESPRIT paper that motivates why you're using the (estimated) autocovariance matrix!")